How to Bulk Update CPT Taxonomy Values Using CSV Lookup Table
I have a CPT named Places on a very large website with a few million posts. Each post has a value for the taxonomy States (e.g, FL). Normally I use WP All Import, but it's very slow. Processes about 10k rows per hour, but I need to update 900k posts.
Thought crossed my mind to do something similar to vlookup. If WordPress allowed us to have one table for a CPT then it would be very easy to bulk update values. I created a master table of every single CPT along with all the terms, taxonomies, etc. Took about 5 hours to get everything.
I know I can bulk update the values because I did it months for a different taxonomy using some php code. Problem is I do not remember how I did it as I was hoping to find something like Airtable without a 100k row limitation per table.  Stupid me for not documenting the process.
Code I came up with works for some posts, but not all. Ran a test of 100k updates to replace the value (empty, null or different) of States taxonomy with the values in my test table. It looks like some were updated. Tons of errors though.
WordPress database error Duplicate entry '983102-118270' for key 'wp_term_relationships.PRIMARY' for query UPDATE `wp_term_relationships` SET `term_taxonomy_id` = 118270 WHERE `object_id` = 983102
WordPress database error Duplicate entry '965290-118270' for key 'wp_term_relationships.PRIMARY' for query UPDATE `wp_term_relationships` SET `term_taxonomy_id` = 118270 WHERE `object_id` = 965290

PHP code
<?php
// Include WordPress Configuration
require_once('/home/domain/htdocs/www.domain.com/wp-load.php');

// Initialize necessary variables
global $wpdb;
$log_file = '/home/domain/htdocs/www.domain.com/scripts/taxonomies/update_state_taxonomy_onlyV2.log';
$batch_size = 1000; // Adjust batch size as needed

// Ensure log file is writable
if (!file_exists($log_file)) {
    file_put_contents($log_file, '');
}

if (!is_writable($log_file)) {
    die("Log file is not writable. Please check the permissions.");
}

// Increase lock wait timeout (example: 120 seconds)
$wpdb->query("SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120");

// Get total number of rows to process
$total_rows = $wpdb->get_var(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM domain.import_state_taxonomy_only_2 
     WHERE state IS NOT NULL 
     AND state <> ''"
);

// Calculate total number of batches
$total_batches = ceil($total_rows / $batch_size);

// Iterate through batches
for ($batch = 0; $batch < $total_batches; $batch++) {
    // Start transaction for data integrity
    $wpdb->query('START TRANSACTION');

    try {
        // Fetch a batch of data from the lookup table
        $lookup_data = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT wp_postid, state 
                 FROM domain.import_state_taxonomy_only_2 
                 WHERE state IS NOT NULL 
                 AND state <> ''
                 LIMIT %d OFFSET %d",
                $batch_size, $batch * $batch_size
            ),
            ARRAY_A
        );

        foreach ($lookup_data as $index => $row) {
            $post_id = $row['wp_postid'];
            $state_name = $row['state'];

            // Get the term ID for the new state name
            $term_id = $wpdb->get_var(
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "SELECT term_id FROM {$wpdb->terms} WHERE name = %s",
                    $state_name
                )
            );

                                                            
            if (!$term_id) {
                $message = "State '$state_name' not found for post ID $post_id.\n";
                file_put_contents($log_file, $message, FILE_APPEND);
                continue;
            }

            // Get the term taxonomy ID for 'states'
            $term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->get_var(
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} 
                     WHERE term_id = %d AND taxonomy = 'states'",
                    $term_id
                )
            );

                                                                     
            if (!$term_taxonomy_id) {
                $message = "Taxonomy 'states' not found for term ID $term_id and post ID $post_id.\n";
                file_put_contents($log_file, $message, FILE_APPEND);
                continue;
            }

            // Check if the row exists
            $row_exists = $wpdb->get_var(
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} 
                     WHERE object_id = %d AND term_taxonomy_id = %d",
                    $post_id, $term_taxonomy_id
                )
            );

            if ($row_exists) {
                // Row exists, update the existing row
                $wpdb->update(
                    $wpdb->term_relationships,
                    array('term_taxonomy_id' => $term_taxonomy_id),
                    array('object_id' => $post_id),
                    array('%d'), // Format for term_taxonomy_id
                    array('%d')  // Format for object_id
                );
                $message = "Updated row for post ID {$post_id}.\n";
            } else {
                // Row does not exist, insert a new row
                $wpdb->insert(
                    $wpdb->term_relationships,
                    array('object_id' => $post_id, 'term_taxonomy_id' => $term_taxonomy_id),
                    array('%d', '%d') // Format for object_id and term_taxonomy_id
                );

                                               
                                                                                    
                        
                $message = "Inserted new row for post ID {$post_id}.\n";
        }

            // Log the message
            file_put_contents($log_file, $message, FILE_APPEND);
        }

        // Commit the transaction
        $wpdb->query('COMMIT');
        file_put_contents($log_file, "Batch {$batch} processed successfully!\n", FILE_APPEND);

        // Display progress bar
        $progress = round((($batch + 1) / $total_batches) * 100);
        echo "\rProgress: [";
        echo str_repeat("=", $progress / 2) . str_repeat(" ", 50 - $progress / 2) . "] {$progress}%";
        ob_flush();
        flush();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Rollback the transaction in case of an error
        $wpdb->query('ROLLBACK');
        $error_message = "Error in batch {$batch}: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        file_put_contents($log_file, $error_message, FILE_APPEND);
        echo "\n" . $error_message;
    }
}

echo "\nBulk update complete!\n";
?>

Is there something I'm missing?  I REALLY would prefer to go the database route because it takes way too much time to use the plugin.
Thanks.
